# How to solve this JSON promise error with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to React so there might be a lot of mistakes around. Also, I know there are similar questions, but none helped with my problem so far.

I'm working on a project (using a template) that is using Java Spring (back-end) and ReactJS (front-end).
At the moment I am trying to make a login form, and verify the credentials.

These are the functions that I use when I press Login:

```
    onSubmit(){
        let login = {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        };
        this.checkLogin(login);
    }



    checkLogin(login){

        return this.sendRequest(login, (result, status) => {
            console.log("AICI NU AJUNG CRED");
            if (result !== null && (status === 200 || status === 201)) {
                console.log("Successfully inserted person with id: " + result);
                this.reloadHandler();
            } else {
                console.log("There was an error " + result);
            }
        });
    }


    sendRequest(login, callback){
        let request = new Request(HOST.backend_api + endpoint.login + "/login", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers : {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(login)
        });
        console.log(request.url);
        console.log(login);
        RestApiClient.performRequest(request, callback);
    }


function performRequest(request, callback){

    fetch(request)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                if (response.ok) {
                    response.json().then(json => callback(json, response.status,null));
                }
                else {
                    response.json().then(err => callback(null, response.status,  err));
                }
            })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //catch any other unexpected error, and set custom code for error = 1
            callback(null, 1, err)
        });
}
```

I try it with a  "test" username and "test" password I have in my database.
And this is the result:

[dev console result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPNWx.png)

[dev console result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4yyQ.png)

Comment: Hi Radu, try passing the json as an object (without `JSON.stringify` )  ->   `body: login`

Comment: that doesn't work. If I do it like that, I get 2 errors: Post 400, and Unexpected end of json input

Comment: Try to log `response`, it might not be JSON but plain text..

Comment: This is my logged response: Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/users/login", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}